# Angular System Design - Components

Tags: angular

When creating angular pages, how often should you componentize things?

For example, lets say we have a profile page, should the display picture, status update, user info all be separate components on the profile component?

Or are components meant for things which are reuseable, like a search textbox or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your preference.  The beauty of Angular is that it gives you the option of compartmentalizing your website as much or as little as you want.  Generally speaking, each aspect of your website should be made into a component if it'd be used multiple times around your website.

For your specific example, with multiple users, there likely would be multiple profile pages that would look exactly the same from a structural standpoint, but the content would vary depending on the user that was logged in.  The profile page should be it's own component, but it may be overkill to make the display picture, status update, or user info all as their own separate components, unless the HTML markup is excessively verbose.  All of that user-specific data can be solved using `string-interpolation` and `directives` within the `profile.component.html` template with data passed in from the `profile.component.ts` file.

Comment: if you said that is an overkill to separate the smaller components, how will I easily change later on the status update with this week weather? I will advise for as much as possible componentization where it makes sense (views on the page with same concern) that could be easily replaced when needed. Also, atomic pieces should be reusable components (button, input, grid etc.).

Comment: I think making a component for 1-5 lines of code is definitely overkill, unless this code is used repetitively in your app, then I think it makes sense to make it into a component.  Components also present challenges, including the use of @Input/@Output from parent/child components that can be completely eliminated if it was just in the main template file to begin with.  There's no right or wrong answer, it's a design choice.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you architecture. Generally the more reusable separate components you create, the more modular and testable your application becomes. But you have to be careful maybe there is no need to create a lot of small components. When separating page into separate components you break out things into chunks. But it also takes time to do this